# Data fetch from database

Tags: iphone, sql, database, sqlite

I stored some information in my server. I used JSON for fetching data. The data is fetch and store to device database and fetch from it. The problem is i have some set images in cat_id=1 & some set images in cat_id=2. Now im using different Array for different set of images like `const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product where cat_id = '1'";`, `const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product where cat_id = '2'";`. If i use "%@" this it displays all the values.

code:

First set of images:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { 

const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product where cat_id = '1'"; 

NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql); 

sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
// int catID = 0; 
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
// We "step" through the results - once for each row. 
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 


catName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: 
(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]; 
NSLog(@"catName is %@",catName); 

[mArray addObject:catName]; 
[catName release]; 

// catID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0); 
} 
} 


sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
} 

else { 
sqlite3_close(database); 
NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
// Additional error handling, as appropriate... 
}
```

second set of images:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { 

const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product where cat_id = '2'"; 


NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql); 

sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
// int catID = 0; 
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
// We "step" through the results - once for each row. 
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 


tabName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: 
(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]; 
NSLog(@"tabName is %@",tabName); 

[tabArray addObject:tabName]; 
[tabName release]; 

// catID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0); 
} 
} 
sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
} 

else { 
sqlite3_close(database); 
NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database)); 
// Additional error handling, as appropriate... 
}
```

}

Im using ActionSheet button click for display array of datas:

```
-(void)actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex {

     if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"button");


 for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {
                NSLog(@"index %d",i);



              //  imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 500, 72, 72)];

                imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

                Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

                [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

                [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(arraysofsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [imgView1 setImage:((Mysof *)[mArray objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

              //  [myScroll addSubview:imgView1];



            }




    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSLog(@"button 1");


 for (int i = 0; i<[tabArray count]; i++ ) {
                NSLog(@"index %d",i);



              //  imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 500, 72, 72)];

                imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

                Width = Width + 20+(i*74);

                [imgView1 setTag:i+1];

                [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(arraysofsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                [imgView1 setImage:((Mysof *)[tabArray  objectAtIndex:i]).photo forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];

              //  [myScroll addSubview:imgView1];



            }


    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {


          NSLog(@"button 2");

    } else if (buttonIndex == 3) {

    }
}
```

Here i don't want to use cat_id=1 & cat_id=2. I need to pass any parameter  value for increament automatically and get values from table. Because if i change anything the cat_id is increasing.

Comment: Your question is cluttered with irrelevant code. Please reduce your code dump and limit yourself to showing only what is abolutely necessary. Also, please state precisely what your problem is.

Comment: Im using cat_id for retrieving data. If i edit something the cat_id number is changing. So if i use cat_id="%@" this is getting all the values. How can i pass parameters for looping condition..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties of `cat_id` to not auto increment. Also, the auto increment should only be triggered when you insert a new row into your table.

It seems that `cat_id` is a foreign key for some other table describing a product category. Simply use the `UPDATE TABLE` syntax to change a record (e.g. with a new image), leaving the `cat_id` unchanged.

If the user changes the category of your product, you simply set a new `cat_id`.

In SQLite you substitute variables with `?` and the `sqlite_bind_*` function:

```
const *char sql = "SELECT id, cat_id, product_image FROM product "
                  "WHERE cat_id = ?";
...
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
   if (sqlite3_bind_int(sql, 1, yourCatID) == SQLITE_OK) {
       // iterate through the results with sqlite3_step
   }
}
```

Comment: This is table what i created:   CREATE TABLE "product" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "cat_id" INTEGER NOT NULL , "product_image" VARCHAR NOT NULL , "order_by" INTEGER NOT NULL )

Comment: If i set cat_id unchange means, it display all the images under product_image

Comment: It's not working with your code. I get all the cat_id and stored separate array later when i click the button index i got it.

Comment: If you array does not contain the right items, change it. This site is meant to solve specific programming problems. Your problem was you did not know how to substitute variables into an SQLite sql statement. I showed you how. If you have further questions that are unrelated, ask a different question after accepting the above answer.